# How to actually close a specific connection from PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: apache-httpcomponents

we use the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager through a LoadBalancer.

At some point in time the server returns a 500 (with a special message body), indicating the node can no longer service requests.  At this point we need to tear down this persistent connection, and force the pool to re-establish a new one, which the LB will then connect to a new node that can service requests.

My question is once I get this response..how can we actually close the connection, and NOT return it back to the pool?

our code looks something like:

```
 ---
 cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
 cm.setDefaultConnectionConfig(ConnectionConfig.DEFAULT);
 cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
 cm.setMaxTotal(20);
 httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setConnectionManager(cm)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(reqConfig).build()
 -----

 HttpPut put = new HttpPut(path);
 put.setEntity(new StringEntity(body, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
 try {
    resp = httpClient.execute(target.get(), httpUriRequest);
    httpResponse = new HttpResponse(resp,captureHeaders);
 } 
 finally { 
         put.releaseConnection();  // DOES NOT CLOSE CONNECTION, RETURNS IT TO POOL??
       if (resp != null) {
       try {
           resp.close();  // DOES NOT CLOSE CONNECTION, RETURNS IT THE POOL?
       } 
       catch(IOException e){
             logger.error("exception while closing resp", e);
       }
     }
 }
```

Thanks for any tips/pointers in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `HttpUriGet#releaseConnection()`. It is provided for HC 3.1 compatibility only.

Use either `HttpUriGet#abort()` to abort ongoing request execution and close out the underlying connection, or (recommended) `CloseableHttpResponse#close`, which keeps the connection alive if it is deemed safe to re-use or closes it out (for instance, if there is response content left unconsumed).